# exporting when narrowed to subtree fails due to unresolved references

Tags: org-mode

I am having a large org-mode file and would like to export to HTML only a particular subtree. So I narrow to that subtree using `M-x org-narrow-to-subtree` and then export to HTML with `C-c C-e h h`.

However, the export fails since some references can no longer be resolved (as they point to other parts of the tree), so I simply get a message like the following:

```
Unable to resolve ID "mpm-2015-09-02"
```

The message appears in the mini-buffer and then the export fails.

When I try to export the entire document (without narrowing) I succeed.

Is there any way to instruct org-mode to just export the text of the link instead of failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuraton variable `org-export-with-broken-links` was added quite recently to support this.

You may not be running a sufficiently recent org-mode to get that option, though, since it was only committed in October. It doesn't seem to have landed in the *org-plus-contrib* package I'm running from MELPA, for example (version 20151123).

http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=commitdiff;h=59761024b17b3b71e70b6fde4f8580eb586d2f7b;hp=707fbc37781eea123e70f1c27062a26374e61ef4